# Rails define root url based on Rails Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, environment

Is there any way to define different root url based on Rails environment. I want to set `root :to => 'pages#index'` for development and staging environment and `root :to => 'beta_pages#index'` for production environment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

In your `routes.rb` file:

```
  if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.staging?
    root :to => 'pages#index'
  elsif Rails.env.production?
    root :to => 'beta_pages#index'
  end
```